# How can I pass data from serverside to clientside

Tags: c#, asp.net

I read data from database in sreverside (for example a name) and I want to use this name in clientside. But I don't pass the name to clientside(in javascript method). How can I achieve this?

(using asp.net)

using HiddenField:

serverside:

```
protected void callbackPanel_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
hiddenFieldGenel.Add("license", "license1");
}
```

clientside:

```
<dx:ASPxHiddenField ID="hiddenFieldGenel" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="hiddenFieldGenel">
</dx:ASPxHiddenField>

function saveClick(s, e) {
var licence = hiddenFieldGenel.Get('license');
}
```

Comment: then what do you mean by clientside

Comment: You have several options. If you need to return data on `Page_Load`, you can put it in the `Session` variable and access it from your JavaScript method.

Comment: If your value is in a field, you can get it with JQuery or Javascript.  Note that with ASPX you have to use `<%= FieldName.Text %>` to get the correct field.

Comment: can I access session in clientside? @PoweredByOrange
This field name like a label or textbox?

Comment: You cannot access the session, it exists only on the server.  You need to save your value to a form variable and access it from javascript.  @Rahul's answer is a pretty good explanation.

Comment: You can actually access the Session variable in JS. Something like `var myName = '<%= Session["Name"] %>';` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

If its just a single value, you can use `Hidden` variable:-

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="NameHidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And you can simply access it using Javascript or jQuery:-

```
$('#NameHidden').val();
document.getElementById('NameHidden');
```

Comment: ASPX will change the name of anything set to `runat="server"` unless name is set to static, or is referenced with `<%%>` tags.

Comment: @paqogomez - Updated thnx.

Comment: I tried to use hiddenfield but its content disappear in the javascript method.

Comment: @user983924 - Disappear as in? Where you are reading the value? How you are using?